# PowerBI Last N Months Trend Line - Ignore All Date Filters

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Have a simple, 2 table model: [Sales]*-[Calendar] with sales that span from 1/1/2021 to yesterday. Day grain.  Calendar is a standard date dimension.

Need: I want a line chart that shows the sales trend for each day since the first of the month, 3 months back, to yesterday.

I want this line chart measure to ignore the influence from all Calendar[Date] slicers/filter that happen to be on the report.

I understand I can use the "edit interactions" feature and stop the Date slicers from affecting the trend line - and that works - with this code.

However, I want to learn how to ignore these external filter affects within DAX & **not** rely on using the edit-interaction feature.

I've gotten this far. This code calcs the measure I want, but a date slicer on the report affects it and I don't want it to. What am I missing?

```
 Total $ Last 3 Months Trend = 
VAR __monthsBack = 3
VAR __endDate =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( Sales[SalesDate] ), ALL ( 'Calendar' ) )
VAR __endDateMinus_NMonths =
    EDATE ( __endDate, - __monthsBack )
VAR __firstDate =
    DATE ( YEAR ( __endDateMinus_NMonths ), MONTH ( __endDateMinus_NMonths ), 01 )
RETURN
    IF (
        MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) <= __endDate
            && MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) >= __firstDate,
        CALCULATE (
            [Total $],
            FILTER (
                'Calendar',
                'Calendar'[Date] >= __firstDate
                    && 'Calendar'[Date] <= __endDate
            ),
            REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
        ),
        BLANK ()
    )
```

Comment: Instead of using `REMOVEFILTERS` as a filter parameter within `CALCULATE`, you should be applying an `ALL` to your dates within the `FILTER` clause: `CALCULATE([Total$],FILTER(ALL('Calendar'),'Calendar'[Date]>=__firstDate&&'Calendar'[Date]<=__endDate))`

Comment: Tried that as well. Didn't work. This results in Total$ (which is just SUM(sales)) being totaled for the entire date range instead of filtered per date. So, in my case, every Calendar[Date] on the line chart or matrix is $60,484 instead of each day's total.

Comment: You want it to be filtered by date but simultaneously not filtered by date?! I don't believe you can specifically set a measure to ignore a filter context coming from one source (slicer) but maintain it from another.

Comment: Correct. Hence my fragile understanding of filters applied within the measure versus filters coming from outside it. Second, I suspect that somehow internal to the edit-interactions feature (which does what I want it to) - there's some similar trick being performed that ~should be repo'able using DAX. Thanks.

Comment: I sympathise with your suspicion, though I think you'll find that it's groundless: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/disabling-interaction-using-dax/m-p/892669